# Form target breaks when global variable name is specified inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

You have an `HTML` like this:

```
<form action="frame.html" target="frame1"><input type="submit"></form>
<iframe name="frame1" id="frame1" src="frame.html"></iframe>
```

And it works fine reloading the frame (sending some post data in case of production code). BUT if in the **frame.html** there is a code defining global variable **"name"**, the code breaks and opens **frame.html** in a **new tab** instead.

```
var name = "a";
```

Works the same way in **Chrome** and **Firefox**.

Here's the example on github.io:
http://evigl.github.io/form-target-iframe-test/ 
Sources: https://github.com/EviGL/form-target-iframe-test/tree/gh-pages 
(first frame is normal working frame, second opens new window, several console.log's for clarity).

It's strange, huh? It works the same way even if **frame.html** is on another domain. Doesn't it break Same Origin Policy?

Is there a way to override this behavior? I have some uncontrolled code inside the frame (user-generated code preview), changing it is not an option. And it is also on another domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's strange, huh?

Yes. It's a consequence of very early DOM design which has been kept for backwards compatibility (because browsers won't throw out anything terrible that websites might actually still use).

> Doesn't it break Same Origin Policy?

No. The JS isn't *reading* anything across origins.

> Is there a way to override this behavior?

Not really. You might be able to hack around it by using `getElementById` to assign a new `src` to the frame with JS (I don't know if linking to a new page within the frame would break that though), or by destroying the frame entirely and replacing it with a new one (also with JS).

Comment: _No. The JS isn't reading anything across origins._

But you can bruteforce value of variable "name" on some domain (opening several hundred thousand tabs in the same time). I suppose there is a way to determine in JS if a frame reloaded or a new window opened.

Recreating the iframe will do the job, I think, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Another workaround, don't make it global. Make it accessible by a function.

Comment: @sємsєм — The question says "some uncontrolled code inside the frame (user-generated code preview), changing it is not an option"